# Is it possible to block iTunes notifications while a process is running

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, itunes

I'm working on a iOS app where the user is fetching a reasonably sized database online, and then working with it offline. The update, and sync is taking around 10-15 minutes due to the memory constraints on the device and the way I'm handling the transactional inserts. All the while I have a dialog view open notifying the user of the progress, and give him the option of cancelling and reverting the changes to the database.

Anyway, today while testing I noticed that the iTunes app was trying to contact as server and do some background work, but threw an error:

```
 itunesstored[68] <Warning>: Could not load download manifest with underlying error: 
                             Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "Cannot connect
                             to 112.168.198.2" UserInfo=0x1f8d6150 
                             {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to 112.168.198.2}
```

This caused a dialog to display on top of the one I was already displaying, notifying the user that iTunes was unable to connect.

Now when I clicked the 'close' button, that somehow also closed my dialog, causing only parts of the actions, to be taken when the user decides to stop the update, to take place. The async update kept on going in the background, while the database tried to revert the changes causing the database to lock up and I needed to kill the process and restart the app and update. By design, that reverts everything if something terrible like this happens.

Now I noticed that I should make some changes in my code to make it harder for the database to lock up like that, and I'm working on that. 
But what I want to know is: **is it possible to forbid iTunes, or any other process for that matter, to do any work on the UI thread while a certain critical process in your app is taking place?**

The behavior of the iTunes dialog cancel button, i.e propagating down into my dialog can't be considered normal or reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Apps should be coded in a way that accounts for these kind of interruptions. For instance, on an iPhone, what happens if a telephone call comes in? It's the apps responsibility to deal with it; the system will let the call come through irrespective of your "critical process".

In general, it sounds like your app isn't designed in the best way. For instance, 10 minutes to parse a database seems **extremely** long — how many records does this database have? You should be able to import databases with 100,000 records in a couple of seconds on the iPhone.

Comment: Like I said, this showed me a flaw in my design. But that doesn't change the fact that a iTunes dialog touch event passing through all other displaying dialogs is kind of strange.

Time wise, the data is given to me in JSON form which I need to parse. And trying to get larger JSON strings than what I'm getting now was giving me a memory exception. So I need to fetch a smaller version more often. The data is a 64bit string containing image data. Not the best way perhaps, but in this case my hands are tied.

Comment: I'm not sure on the exact behaviour of multiple `UIAlertView`'s but I think your alert should remain if the iTunes one is interacted with. On the data front, when you say 64bit image data as a string — do you mean base64?

Comment: Yeah, sorry meant base64. I haven't been able to reproduce the situation so I can't see what actually happens with the alertview. Will just have to try to handle it as best as I can.

Comment: Regarding the import of the database, you could import the strings. Then, decode the images themselves at a later date, maybe through lazy instantiation?